# Extract embedded subtitles

Tags: video-subtitles

I have a couple of video files which are subtitled in English. Unfortunately the subtitling is encoded into the video bitstream. I would like to extract the titles (as UTF8 …).

Is there a tool to do that? If not, how would you go about it?

Python preferred. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure python is a good idea unless there are modules to parse video formats and decode them.

Here's a better solution: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ExtractSubtitles